# Mac Appstore updates repeating each day, even though packages installed already

Tags: macos, software-update

**NOT Answered**. Having looked in /var/log/install.log during two new update requests, I see this on both instances.

```
SUAppStoreUpdateController: did not start session for 031-10481 (previously installed?)
```

The session number is different for each package of course.
**I can verify that both packages are in fact installed,** because running them returns the correct version numbers.
The packages are **Command Line Tools**, and **Safari.9**

Now there is only the question left.
**Why is the AppStore Update manager listing the updates as being available each day. Even though the packages are already installed.**

Comment: I had this and a reboot seemed to solve this - I needed up with AppStore app telling me I had installed command line tools twice

Comment: It's driving me nuts. It is throwing errors during install, which is probably causing the repeat. But it won't install either with AppStore, softwareupdate, or Pacifist.

Comment: How much spare disk space do you have?

Comment: 226GB on a 1 TB drive